# pentaho redirecting if entered base url to a dashboard

Tags: tomcat, redirect, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am using pentaho listening on port 8080, I need to redirect the user after login to a specific dashboard URL if its not admin, i know the admin condition, and then i have checked if the BROWSER URL is == http://localhost:8080 , it should redirect, but its not working.

```
if( Dashboards.context.user == "admin" && window.location.href == "http://localhost:8080" || window.location.href == "http://localhost:8080/" )
   {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:public:TM:DailyDashboard.wcdf/generatedContent";
   }
```

please if anyone can suggest me what am doing wrong here? and what approach should be the best...

Comment: if you are not familiar with Pentaho, then its of no use to explain this...

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. Please, try to use window.top in your condition: `if( Dashboards.context.user == "admin" && (window.top.location.href == "http://localhost:8080" || window.top.location.href == "http://localhost:8080/") )`. It worked for me. (However, for me path was like http://localhost:8080/pentaho/Home?locale=en_US)

Comment: have you tried it on pentaho?

Comment: Yes. Worked on Pentaho 5.2 both in preview and once opened via browse files. But I had to place different link into conditions (maybe we have different server settings). BTW, the script was just placed as an <script></script> in html tab.

Comment: which file you have used?i have placed it in the cpk.html file of my template and it don't work :(

Comment: I haven't used templates. I went to "Layout panel", added row, then added html with the script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111125/discussion-between-user4637357-and-shzyincu).